# Можно ли отключить windows defender программно?

Tags: windows, powershell, командная-строка, defender

Можно ли отключить windows defender программно?

Comment: А зачем вам, простите? Вы пишете какой-то троян?

Comment: @VladD Не обязательно. Такая необходимость возникает, к примеру, если нужно скопировать массу мелких файлов, в которых гарантированно нет вирусов, тогда первой командой отключаешь Дефендер, затем batch copy, затем включаешь обратно. Получается быстрее.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Это **крайне** некорректно по отношению к пользователю. Пользователь не разрешал вам отключать антивирусную защиту.

Comment: @VladD Ммм... к какому пользователю? Я сам пользователь в этом случае, когда копирую данные. А если же речь о том, чтобы скрипт топик-стартера таким образом отключит Defender на компьютере иного пользователя, то система не даст это сделать, как минимум, без запроса админовских прав (исключение: пользователь отключил все защиты и сидит под админом, но тут уж он сам себе злейший враг)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Ну поскольку у нас тут онтопик — программирование, а не использование компьютера, то речь идёт о программе, выполняющейся на машине _другого_ пользователя.

Comment: @VladD Тогда в силе остаётся мой комментарий про UAC и иже с ними: запрос от системы в случае такой попытки поступит, кроме случаев "особо одарённых"  (и некоторых особо доверчивых) пользователей

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Пользователь имеет право быть доверчивым, он не специалист. Большинство пользователей не считают, что программа, которая бежит у него на компьютере, будет делать что-то враждебное. Вот вам аналогия: представьте себе, что ваш автомобиль спросил, имеет ли он право на админские полномочия, а если вы согласитесь, катапультирует вас из салона. Это ведь не считается нормальным? Почему же тогда считается нормальным навредить пользователю, который не знает, чем чревато соглашение с программой?

Comment: @VladD вы предлагаете скрывать подобную информацию? Её найдут в другом месте. Подозреваю, что данная дискуссия уместна, скорее, в Meta, чем здесь.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Нет, скрыть информацию не получится. Но я бы написал в ответе большими буквами: **никогда** не делайте так на машине пользователя. На своей — сколько угодно.

Comment: @VladD ОК, убедили :) Но, максимум, что поможет сделать эта надпись, на мой взгляд, это очистить нашу с вами совесть :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Злонамеренного программиста она всё равно не остановит, он найдёт информацию тут или где-то ещё. А нормальный, прочитав это, подумает, и, возможно, поменяет путь к решению проблемы.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Да, можно. Однако, необходимо помнить, что вы отключаете программное средство защиты. На своём компьютере вы вольны проделывать любые эксперименты, на компьютере иного пользователя вы **обязаны заранее предупредить его об этом**.
Итак, отключение:

```
sc stop WinDefend
```

включаем затем:

```
sc start WinDefend
```

проверяем:

```
sc query WinDefend
```

Можно с запретом на старт:

```
sc config WinDefend start= disabled
sc stop WinDefend
```

Не забываем об админских правах!

В Windows 10 придётся воспользоваться Powershell:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true  # запрет
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false # разрешение
```

На правах комментария, поскольку к вопросу особого отношения не имеет: замечено, что в Windows 10, даже при отключенном Defender (а он, кстати, отключается не навсегда, а на небольшое время), логирование изменений на диске продолжается, и сразу после включения Defender "бросается" проверять то, что было изменено, когда он был выключен.

**Update 1.** Начиная с версии 1703, контроль ядра не выключается.

Comment: [SC] OpenService: ошибка: 5:

Отказано в доступе.

Это при выполнении: sc stop WinDefend

Comment: запускаю разумеется от имени администратора

Comment: @relevant sc query WinDefend - тоже?

Comment: нет это работает, отказ доступа только при `sc stop WinDefend`

Comment: @relevant Понял, у вас Windows 10 :) Сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: Я бы добавил ещё, что пробел в `start= disabled` обязателен и без него работать не будет.

Comment: @donRumata Да, это верно

Answer (score -1):

Я сделал не большую софтину, которая может отключать Windows 10 defender, кроме смарт фильтра. Это в дополнение к ответу. Есть определённые ключи реестра.

[Статья](https://vk.com/wall-39869096_187)

Только на видео ошибся. Нужно все параметры указывать без кавычек. Язык C#.

[Ещё статья, где указано как исправить ошибки](https://vk.com/wall-39869096_216)

Вот общий принцип того, что нужно будет сделать. Всё это (на видео) можно перевести в код (а в статье можно скачать программу и посмотреть как это будет работать).

1) В редакторе реестра перейдите к разделу HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SOFTWARE\ Policies\ Microsoft\ Windows Defender

2) В правой части редактора реестра нажмите правой кнопкой мыши, выберите «Создать» — «Параметр DWORD 32 бита» (даже если у вас 64-бит система) и задайте имя параметра DisableAntiSpyware

3) После создания параметра дважды нажмите по нему и задайте значение 1.

4) Там же создайте параметры AllowFastServiceStartup и ServiceKeepAlive — их значение должно быть 0 (ноль, задается по умолчанию).

5) В разделе Windows Defender выберите подраздел Real-Time Protection (или создайте его), а в нем создайте параметры с именами DisableIOAVProtection и DisableRealtimeMonitoring
6) Дважды кликните по каждому из этих параметров и задайте значение 1.

7) В разделе Windows Defender создайте подраздел Spynet, в нем создайте параметры DWORD32 с именами DisableBlockAtFirstSeen (значение 1), LocalSettingOverrideSpynetReporting (значение 0), SubmitSamplesConsent(значение 2). 
Это действие отключает проверку в облаке и блокировку неизвестных программ.
Готово. После этого можно закрывать редактор реестра. Защитник Windows почти отключен. Осталось небольшое действие.

Переходим в «Диспетчер задач», вкладка «Автозагрузка» и отключаем «Windows Defender», перезагружаем компьютер и радуемся. Защитник полностью отключён.

По ошибкам:
Вы могли почитать статьи по ссылкам или я напишу ниже.

Код программы не идеален, но всё же работает и с результатом!
Программу запускать от имени Администратора ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО!
Ещё один момент. Если после выполнения всех действий блокируется только "Мониторинг", то при указании значений просто уберите кавычки. 
Пример: Registry.SetValue(keyName1, "DisableBlockAtFirstSeen", "1"); заменить на Registry.SetValue(keyName1, "DisableBlockAtFirstSeen", 1); Последний параметр передаём без кавычек. От этого изменится тип данных в реестре на DWORD (Двойное слово).

Почему это дополнение к предыдущему ответу?

Потому, что в предыдущем ответе останавливают процесс не руками. В моём случае этого не избежать, но можно совместить оба ответа в единый. Тогда Защитник будет и остановлен и вообще заблокирован и никогда больше не включится (если Вы сами этого не захотите).

Вот пример кусочка кода для Visual C# Express 2010 
Событие по щелчку на кнопку

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 const string userRoot = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE";
 const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender";
 const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

 Registry.SetValue(keyName, "DisableAntiSpyware", 1);
 Registry.SetValue(keyName, "AllowFastServiceStartup", 0);
 Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ServiceKeepAlive", 0);

 //и так далее, как выше изложено, проходимся по оставшимся веткам и ключам
}
```

Ну и добавить автоматическую остановку процесса "защитника".
Внимание, если Вы будете использовать этот код, например, в Visual Studio, то можете столкнуться с ошибками т.к. там обращение к реестру происходит несколько иначе (я уже пробовал).

Comment: "Это в дополнение к ответу" - что вы имеете в виду, к какому ответу? И кроме того, ответ содержащий только ссылки, не считается ответом и обычно удаляется.

Comment: Тогда я подредактирую. А дополнение - тоже программный способ, но несколько иначе.

Comment: Ссылку на youtube уберите, интересен только код в виде текста, а не как картинка или видео.

Comment: Вообще программирование по видосику это какая-то непонятная вещь... это для малограмотных, что ли?

Comment: Вообще да. Иногда я показываю какие-то вещи очень наглядно.